# Customized MOSFET in SPICE

Tags: mosfet, analog, spice

Is it possible in SPICE to create a MOSFET with user defined values of V_T(Threshold Voltage)?

This question cropped up because I was taking a course on Analog Design with videos & problem sets(**without answers**) available online.I got stuck in the problem sets and have no way to verify my answer and thought process.So I thought instead of shamelessly posting the question  here, simulation of the circuit would solve the problem and increase my intuition & understanding.

But I discovered that only specific models from various Companies are available.

The only parameter I want to change is V_T?Is there any way to 'create' such a component and simulate it???

Comment: Usually on simulators you can open the model of a device and edit various parameters. I think Vgs might be what you are looking for. Maybe your version doesn't allow this?

Comment: What SPICE and MOSFET?

Comment: @MattYoung:LTSpice

Answer (score 1):

If you have issue wrt LTSpice, you can post the question on LTSpice forum on Yahoo. Otherwise, take a MOSFET spice file in text format, create your own symbol in LTSpice and simulate. This particular method we exactly use when, expected components are not available in library.

Comment: Thanks I found the required stuff here: http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/lt_spice/ltspice_lt_spice.htm